# How to cancel `wp_print_scripts`?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script

I want to load all the scripts in `$wp_scripts` with my own JS function after the `window.onload` event. Is there a simple way to prevent `wp_print_scripts` from printing the default list of `<script>` tags so I can replace it with my own code?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code to see if there is a filter hook you can use?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook [Here's the source code for the function.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L65) I don't see any filters. I also looked through the [filter reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and didn't get any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, but it's not recommended since there might be some other inline scripts attached to the enqueued scripts. You can hook to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and empty the global `$wp_scripts` as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_all_scripts', 1000 );
function remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
```

You can then run a loop and enqueue do whatever you want with them.